# Cannot convert value of type [[EVObject]?] to expected argument type [_]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, reflection, network-programming

I am using Promise Kit for swift 3.0 and I am trying to fulfill my asynchronous network call with the

```
response.result.value
```

So I can use it in my ViewController function:

```
FeedbackServices.getFeedbackSubjects().then { (FeedbackSubject) -> Void in
            print(FeedbackSubject.count)
        }.catch { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

***This is my network layer:***

```
protocol NetworkService
{
    static func GET<T:EVObject>(URL: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, headers: [String: String]?) -> Promise<T>
    static func GET<T:EVObject>(URL: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, headers: [String: String]?) -> Promise<[T]>

}

extension NetworkService
{

    static func GET<T:EVObject>(URL: String,
                    parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil,
                    headers: [String: String]? = nil) -> Promise<[T]>
    {

        return Promise { fullFill, reject in

            Alamofire.request(URL,
                              method: .get,
                              parameters: parameters,
                              encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                              headers: headers).responseArray(completionHandler: { response in

                        if (response.result.isSuccess) {

                            fullFill([response.result.value])

                        }else{
                            reject(response.result.error!)
                        }
                  })
            }
    }
```

***When I try to build the project I get the following error:***

[image]

I am stuck for a few hours now at work and I don't get it working. For any additional information please do not hesitate to ask me!.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with giving the "response" in the completion handler:

```
response: DataResponse<[T]>
```

Best,
Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is on this line?

```
fullFill([response.result.value])
```

Based on the error it looks as if you are supposed to pass an array but you are passing an array of arrays :) So, I suspect that response.result.value might already be an array. Check to see if that is the case. If it is, change the line to:

```
fullFill(response.result.value)
```

Comment: the fix is above your answer! It was the completion handlers type.